# Android WiFi Debugging option not exist. How can i open it?

Tags: android, adb, wifi

I have a special android device with Android 10 version. In the developer options of the device there is no wifi debugging option but, the device supports the wifi debugging. I tested it from Android Studio Wifi ADB tool. However, I want to enable this option in order to run the adb shell commands on the phone without computer or another device. There are several applications for this aim. But these applications can not connect the port of the device probably with `adb tcpip 5555` command cause of the wifi debugging problem. I only can use these application after the Android Studio Wifi ADB connection. The result is here Android Studio - Wifi ADB can enable the Wifi-Debugging of the smartphone programmatically. I wonder how can it do this operation.

Developer Options (debugging) of the device: (https://img.ssyukle.com/image/n8f8W)

Developer Options (network) of the device: (https://img.ssyukle.com/image/n8rht)

I hope I explained my problem and possible solution way correctly. I would be very happy if you can help (with this way or with a different way) to enable wifi debugging. Thank you forward.

Comment: Wifi debugging starts only with Android 11 devices. But indeed what you want should be possible. Never tried.

Comment: @blackapps could you convert your comment to regular answer?

Comment: Did you manage to find an answer to this? Is it possible that the "Wireless Debugging" option is accessible for toggling but hidden?

Comment: @conanDrum the first comment is true. Wifi debugging doesn't work except USB connection and trying to run ADB Wifi tool of Android Studio below Android 11. After Android 11, there is Wireless Debugging settings at Developer Options to do it without cable. However, for the first connection always need a cable connection for security i guess.

Answer (score -1):

Ensure that your device is running Android 11 (API level 30) or higher for phone
or Android 13 (API level 33) or higher for TV and WearOS.
Ref: https://developer.android.com/tools/adb